# getting error when install python word2vec

Tags: python, word2vec

i getting the following error when i install python word2vec. What should I do?

```
imeg@doron:~$ pip install word2vec
Downloading/unpacking word2vec
  Downloading word2vec-0.8.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package word2vec
    /tmp/ccsChX8k.s: Assembler messages:
    /tmp/ccsChX8k.s:2867: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%r12),%xmm0,                                                                                                             %xmm11'
    /tmp/ccsChX8k.s:2886: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 4(%r12),%xmm0                                                                                                             ,%xmm1'
```

Comment: You would probably get a better answer here: https://github.com/danielfrg/word2vec/issues

Comment: Have you tried to install gensim instead? 
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html